# monetdb: switch off password on mclient

Tags: sql, bash, monetdb

I'd like to access monetdb database without password verification. I need this to put code into bash script and automatize some queries.

Command

```
mclient -u monetdb -d database
```

asks for password, which I'd like to omit (by default password is 'monetdb'). After this command I'd like to enter the database.

If it's not feasible, maybe there is a chance to pass the password (even with direct and visible text in code).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a configuration file that contains your username and password.

> Before mclient starts parsing command line options, it reads a .monetdb file. If the environment variable DOTMONETDBFILE is set, it reads the file pointed to by that variable instead. When unset, mclient searches for a .monetdb file in the current working directory, and if that doesn’t exist, in the current user’s home directory. This file can contain defaults for the flags user, password, language, save_history, format, and width. For example, an entry in a .monetdb file that sets the default language for mclient to mal looks like this: language=mal. To disable reading the .monetdb file, set the variable DOTMONETDBFILE to the empty string in the environment.

Put this into your *.monetdb* file and you won't have to manually enter your username and password.

```
user=monetdb
password=monetdb
```

Comment: This didn't work for me

Answer (score -2):

My minimum requirements has fulfilled well-known **expect** command