# monetdb: properly creating and setting the configuration file .monetdb for a user other than monetdb

Tags: monetdb

My goal is to connect to a newly created database named `mydb` through a new user named `jpriest` instead of the default user `monetdb`.

Following this question [monetdb: switch off password on mclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31821309/monetdb-switch-off-password-on-mclient) and the answer provided, I configured a .monetdb file in the current working directory containing the following content:

```
user=jpriest
password=mypassword
language=sql
```

however I received the following error message

`InvalidCredentialsException:checkCredentials:invalid credentials for user 'jpriest'`

I am trying to follow the
[Getting Started](https://www.monetdb.org/index.php/Documentation/Tutorial/GettingStarted/CreateADatabase) section that states :

```
To connect/login to the database server the first time,
you must use monetdb as user name and enter its default password: monetdb.

Once connected you may create new users, create new schemas, create tables etc.
It is also strongly recommended to change the default password of the monetdb system user
via ALTER USER SET PASSWORD command.
```

Since I have not managed to make it work any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I solved the problem through the following steps:

1. I deleted the .monetdb file I previously created.
2. I created a dbfarm named `mydbfarm` via: `monetdbd create mydbfarm`
3. I configured the monetdb deamon `monetdbd` that serves the connections to the databases in `mydbfarm` to listen to the port 54321 via: `monetdbd set port=54321 mydbfarm`
4. I started my dbfarm named `mydbfarm` via: `monetdbd start mydbfarm`
5. I created a database named `mydb` via: `monetdb -p 54321 create mydb`
6. I released `mydb` via :  `monetdb -p 54321 release mydb`
7. I started `mydb` via : `monetdb -p 54321 start mydb`
8. I connected to `mydb` thought mclient via: `mclient -d mydb -p 54321`. I typed `monetdb` for user and again `monetdb` for password
9. If all steps are done correctly the SQL prompt should start.
10. I proceeded with the following command to create a `user` *jpriest* with `password` *monetdb*,  `name` *inpap* and `schema` "sys" via: `CREATE USER "jpriest" WITH PASSWORD 'monetdb' NAME 'inpap' SCHEMA "sys";`
11. After that I log out of the sql prompt with \q and connect again to mydb but this time with the user `jpriest` that I created in step 10 via: `mclient -d mydb -p 54321` and by typing `user`*jpriest*
    `password`*monetdb*
12. Then in the sql prompt we change the password of the user *jpriest* from `monetdb` to `pass` via the command: `ALTER USER SET PASSWORD 'pass' USING OLD PASSWORD 'monetdb'`;
13. Then exiting the prompt and creating the .monetdb file with the content :

```
user=jpriest
password=pass
language=sql
```

will allow you to always log in as `user` *jpriest* with the `password` *pass*

Comment: This is correct. But you could set the intended password in one go, without the intermediate 'monetdb'.

Comment: @JoerivanRuth to make sure I understood correctly, it suffices in step 10 to use WITH PASSWORD 'pass' directly instead of WITH PASSWORD 'monetdb'?

Comment: indeed, you can say WITH PASSWORD 'secret'

Comment: Thank you very much @JoerivanRuth!